# Facebook Javascript API "This authorization code has been used" on quick screen refresh (F5 or COMMAND+R)

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I'm using the Facebook Javascript API for login in conjunction with the official Facebook PHP SDK on my server to execute the two following lines of code:

```
$helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();
$accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
```

With the token, I'm further able to execute this code which gets the necessary details I need on the server:

```
$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($accessToken);
$response = $fb->get('/me?locale=en_US&fields=name,first_name,last_name,email,gender');
```

If I refresh the webpage I'm working with and let it fully load everything works correctly and I'm able to print to screen all of the details I get back in $response.

The *problem* I'm having, however, is that if I quickly refresh the screen (either by hitting F5 on Windows machines or COMMAND+R on Macs) before the Facebook javascript code executes I get the following thrown error from the Facebook API:

"This authorization code has been used"

How do I avoid this?  Do I wrap the Facebook code on the client side in a jQuery document ready function?  I hesitate to do that because I've been told that the Facebook Javascript code is good to go as a stand-alone script that is intelligent enough to know when the document is loaded.

I'm about ready to throw in the towel and just code a manual login process that totally bypasses the Facebook Javascript API.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Put the access code into a **$_session['access_token']** and then redirect to another page to get the data.

1. Login Page
2. Callback Page (save into the session variable)
3. Working Page (work with the session variable)

See more: https://benmarshall.me/facebook-php-sdk/#example-login